# boilerpipe web API

Tags: java, boilerpipe

I would like to host my own version of the boilerpipe web API (http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). The appspot site is http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/

I would like to self host it. Can someone give me directions on how to use the Boilerpipe JAR to create a webpage ?

Comment: Did you ever get this running? I'm working in Node.js and I'm really interested in getting Boilerpipe to work. I'm not very good in Java, so it would be easier to just have a service running on localhost, then to write some kind of interface.

Answer (score 10):

I am the author of `boilerpipe`.

Boilerpipe's demo web application `boilerpipe-web` is not part of the `boilerpipe-core jar`.
To imitate its functionality you will need to write some Java `Servlet` around `boilerpipe-core`.

I'll probably release the source of `boilerpipe-web` at some point, so you don't have to bother with.

Comment: Dr. Kohlschütter, have you made any progress on the release of the `boilerpipe-web` source? I too would be very interesting in using it. Many thanks.